# SiteMap Breadcrumb Navigation for Parentweb

Tags: 2007, master-page, navigation, site, breadcrumb

I am able to get URL of parent web using this code

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

but I am not sure how can I get site Map navigation of parent web so that I can add another breadcrumb to it.